# Why "The data constructors of ‘Path’ are not all in scope" when imported with `Path (..)`

Tags: haskell

The current package imports indirectly the constructor `Path(..)` which, in modules closer  in the chain of imports to the source, can be used to derive `Read` but when I try to use it later in a standalone deriving clause  I get

```
  • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Read (Path Abs Dir)’:
            The data constructors of ‘Path’ are not all in scope
              so you cannot derive an instance for it
        • In the stand-alone deriving instance for ‘Read (Path Abs Dir)’
```

The module code gives no error and imports `Path(..)`. What is missing in the import?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving  #-}

module Uniform.Convenience.StartApp(
    module Uniform.Convenience.StartApp
        )   where


import UniformBase
import UniformBase (Path(..), Read(..))

data Aby = Aby44 Int  (Path Abs Dir)  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show )
deriving instance Read (Path Abs Dir)
```

Comment: Some modules do not expose (all) data constructors.

Comment: Your "additional puzzle" looks like a separate question. It would greatly benefit from specific code and error messages, rather than lengthy prose asking readers to mentally reassemble what's going on.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have checcked that Path is exposed and can be imported with Path(..). How can something be missing in (..)?

Comment: @user855443: because it can be exported as `module MyModule(SomeType(Datac1, Datac2, Datac4)`, so here the `Datac3` data constructor is *not* exported.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: I have removed what appeared as a separate question. I do not see easily, how to expose a multi-level import chain in code and do not have a hint why a direct import is different from a chain of imports and exports of modules in their entirety.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I am sorry for not having been precise: in the case in discussion, the imports and exports are always all what a module exports (as you can see in the shown module, which exports `module xx`. Is it possible that something is not exported in such a case, espcially is it possible that an instance is not exported (and in consequence not imported)? My understanding is that Haskell always exports and imports all instances (a consequence of the 'open world logic'). This is probably the gist of the question.

Comment: @user855443:but you only show the module where you *import* the data, not the one that *exports* it, since Daniel Wagner's example shows that the module can decide to only export a subset. In fact that is very common, since some data constructors only work if a certain number of conditions are met.

Comment: I work on a reduced example, folling the advice I received. The comments listing all the points where an export can be lost. were important to construct a reduced example. The reduced example seems to work, therefore the problem is somewhere in the embedding of the simple working in the complicated code. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

A minimal version of this looks like:

```
module A (Foo(Exported)) where
data Foo = Exported | Not

module B where
import A(Foo(..))
```

Since `Not` is not exported from `A`, it cannot be imported, *even* by the syntax `import A(Foo(..))`. Only `Exported` will be in scope in `B`.

Something similar is happening to you: somewhere along the import chain, one of the modules has chosen not to export at least one of the constructors of `Path`, for one reason or another (probably in part to prevent `Read` instances ;-).

You say:

> in the case in discussion, the imports and exports are always all what a module exports (as you can see in the shown module, which exports `module xx`).

You may find this excerpt of the section of the Report [on exports](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1000005.2) interesting:

> The form “module M” names the set of all entities that are in scope with both an unqualified name “e” and a qualified name “M.e”.

In particular, consider

```
module A (module A) where data Foo = Exported | Not
module B (module A) where import A(Foo(Exported))
module C where import B(Foo(..))
```

Again, in module `C` the `Not` constructor will not be in scope. This time, it is because it was not imported by `B`, and therefore not exported by it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the reason `Path` was not available in the module that imported it. It was shadowed in an intermediate module which imported and exported it wholly (somewhat similar to what @DanielWagner suggested):

```
module UniformBase 
    (  module Uniform.FileIO
    , Generic
    , Read 
    , Path (..)
    ) where

import Uniform.FileIO
```

I had inserted `Path (..)` there for good measure, to insure it is REALLY  exported, and the effect was exactly the opposite. `Path (..)` was found somehere and replaced the one I wanted to export. After removing `Path (..)` from the export list the `Path` imported with Uniform.FileIO was available.

Subtle error, hard to understand (where did the wrong `Path(..)` come from ?) and time consuming to identify (the caching of cabal build did not help!).  I observed that the error disappeared when I imported `Uniform.FileIO` directly and in addition to `UniformBase'.

Comment: Hm. If this is true and reproducible, it sounds like a bug to me. Can you cook up a minimal reproducible example? I think the GHC folks would be interested to see it on their bug tracker. Deleting exports should not expand the collection of things exported.

Comment: I will see if I can cook a smaller example, which can be studied. It needs quite a bit of removing but preserving the issue which cause the problem. If I succeed, I will post it on the GHC bug tracker.